# What is causing this completely bizarre behavior with mod_rewrite?

Tags: mod-rewrite, .htaccess

Here is my rule:

```
RewriteRule ^user/(\d+)$ rewrite.php?id=$1
```

This redirects, but `$_GET['id']` is not set. If I change the above rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^anything/(\d+)$ rewrite.php?id=$1
```

It works. Why does one work but not the other?

Here is more information:

- There is no directory named `user`
- The only other .htaccess file in the hierarchy is blank.
- `anything` can be replaced by anything other than `user`.

**Update:** I checked the `rewritelog` and it's empty.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the cause of the problem... Apparently (and this is documented nowhere that I could find) if you have a file (in this case, PHP) *with the same name as the first virtual directory* the rewrite rule doesn't work. (Redirect loops, missing parameters, etc.)

For example, the following rule:

```
#RewriteRule ^user/(\d+)$ user.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Will malfunction if there is a file named user.php *in the same directory as the PHP file*.

Comment: You probably have activated `mod_speling` (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_speling.html) in your Apache httpd configuration which causes this effect.

Comment: Nope. A quick check shows that mod_speling is disabled.

Comment: Disable MultiViews.

Answer (score 1):

This will happen if `MultiViews` is enabled (part of mod_negotiation). If MultiViews is enabled and you request `/user`, where `/user.php` exists as a physical file then mod_negotiation triggers an internal subrequest for `users.php` (it "searches" for an appropriate file that would return the correct mime-type).

You need to disable MultiViews in your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

MultiViews is disabled by default on Apache, however, some shared hosts do enable this for some reason.